If $f= \sum_{j=1}^{n}r_j\chi _{R_j}$ is simple, then why $X = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}R_J$?
Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a semi-ring over a non-empty set $X$ and let $f: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. We say that $f$ is simple (or $\mathcal {S}$-simple) when there are $r_1,..,r_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $R_1,...,R_n \in \mathcal{S}$ disjoint for which $f= \sum_{j=1}^{n}r_j\chi _{R_j}$.
Comments on notation: Let $\chi _ E$ be the characteristic function (with domain $X$) of a set $E\subseteq X$.
The first step in developing the theory is to prove that the integral of simple functions is linear. In proving this statement, we use the fact that $X = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}R_J$. I can't understand why this is true, could anyone help me?

If not, one can essentially add a term with coefficient $r_0=0$ to achieve this relation. It doesn't change the value of $f$.
